# DB2 via IBM Client Access ODBC Driver - list all tables and columns

Tags: db2

im connected with an DB2 database via IBM Client Access ODBC Driver.
How can i list all tables and columns?

Like in SQL-Server information_schema.columns or in Oracle all_tab_columns?

Regards,
Dennis

Comment: probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List all tables and columns

```
select * from qsys2.syscolumns
```